# Select the last two row from a table and storing them in another table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image: data of the data base tables]

I have a table which is updated with new data every 15 seconds in  time and I want to select the last tow row (the new data stored in the table) and save it in another table every time get updated (the new table have only two row which can replace every time).

I try to select the last data but I don't know how to replace it every 15 second in the second table.

```
SELECT TOP 20 [Index]
      ,[SourceIndex]
      ,[Timestamp]
      ,[CounterID]
      ,[Value]
      ,[Name]
FROM [BDCS].[dbo].[Vcd.CounterValues]
ORDER BY 'Index' desc;
```

Can someone please tell me how to do that?

Comment: See examples of how to use `after update` triggers [Example](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/after-update-triggers-in-sql-server/)

Comment: @sami . . . Why bother?  Why not just fetch the last two rows? It should be quite fast using an index on the identity column.

Comment: @GordonLinoff .. I wanted to store the data in another table first but it was little bit complicated. At the end i fetched the last two row directly. thank you very much guys.